# springfox-data-rest configuration not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, springfox

I follow the [link](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#springfox-swagger-ui) to config.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency> 

@Configuration
@Import( {springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
     ......
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "mails", path = "mails")
public interface TMessageMailDao extends   PagingAndSortingRepository<TMessageMail, Long>{


}
```

But when I open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, there is nothing.

I know springfox-data-rest is still in incubation. Is that the reason it's not work? Or anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

- You are missing `@EnableSwagger2` annotation.
- Make sure to create a `Docket` bean as shown in the example below.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @Import({SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
  @EnableSwagger2
  public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      ...
      @Bean
      public Docket api() {
          return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
              .groupName("example")
              .select()
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())
              .build()
              .apiInfo(apiInfo("Example API", "Example API"));
      }

      private ApiInfo apiInfo(String title, String description) {
           return new ApiInfoBuilder()
               .title(title)
               .description(description)
               .build();
     }
  }
  ```
- Make sure to add the following dependencies:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Once it's working, your `swagger-ui.html` will look something like this:

[image]

> I want to scan two packages. How to include two base packages and not one?

#### Just Controllers

If you are just interested in including REST controllers and not any repository, you can specify any number of packages within `apis` method of Docket with the help of a custom method.

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("book")
                .select()
                .apis(exactPackages("com.basaki.controller", "com.basaki.model"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo("Example Springfox API",
                        "Example Springfox API"));
    }

    private static Predicate<RequestHandler> exactPackages(
            final String... pkgs) {
        return input -> {
            String currentPkg = 
                input.declaringClass().getPackage().getName();
            for (String pkg : pkgs) {
                if (pkg.equals(currentPkg)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
```

#### Controllers and Repositories

If you are interested in including REST controllers and repositories, you have to take advantage of `paths` method in Docket with the help of a custom method. The custom method takes path regexes.

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("book")
                .select()
                .paths(matchPathRegex("/books(/|$).*",
                    "/booxs(/|$).*", "/tokens(/|$).*",
                    "/ping(/|$).*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo("Example Springfox API",
                        "Example Springfox API"));
    }

    private static Predicate<String> matchPathRegex(final String... pathRegexs) {
        return new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(String input) {
                for (String pathRegex : pathRegexs) {
                    if (input.matches(pathRegex)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: sorry， I did not post the swagger configuration，in fact， swagger work well in my application。 I use spring data rest， and I want spring  data rest integrate with swagge。Springfox just scan Controller class, spring data rest use AbstractRepositoryRestController, which does not extends Controller.

Comment: The above screenshot is that of a JPA repository and not a controller. Springfox Data REST worked for me. [Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-fox-examples) is a complete working example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your demo is perfect !!! I still have one little question, to use swagger , I have to comment .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.xxxx")), but I  want to scan two packages. how to include two base package not one.

Comment: Updated my posting with the answer to your last comment.

Comment: this doesnt work with jpa REST repositories and spring boot 2

Comment: @KalpeshSoni correct, support for REST repositories for Spring Boot 2 is broken in SpringFox. Supposed to be fixed in SpringFox 3.0 but that one seems delayed pretty much indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Indra Basak 's help.
My configuration just have one problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
```

This three annotations have to use together.  I config @EnableSwagger2 in another configuration file.

Comment: You can use @EnableSwagger2 in a different file. I usually declare this annotation in my swagger configuration file